# Import module file with folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, directory, require

so i'm trying to make a npm module, and in a moment, i've see a module required like this (example): `const module = require("module.js/folder")`

When i try manually in my test folder, no function returned.

My files and folder:

### test.js

```js
const mymodule = require("./moduleFolder");

const module = new mymodule.module("something"); // Doesn't exist.
const more = new mymodule.more(true); // Doesn't exist.
```

### moduleFolder/file.js

```js
class module {
  constructor(some) {
    this.some = some;
  }
    foo() {
      return "Hey, this is my module!";
    }
};

module.exports = { module };
```

### moduleFolder/file2.js

```js
class more {
  constructor(enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
  }
    foo() {
      if (this.enabled) {
     return "Hey, this thing have been enabled";
      } else {
     return "Hey, this thing have been disabled";
      }
};

module.exports = { more };
```

Do i need to require like this when i've been published the module?

```js
const mymodule = require("module.js/moduleFolder/file");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the path of the module ( which is a file ) that exports constants, variables, or functions! So you giving the path only to folders does not work. You need give relative path to the file.